# How can i make a container resize properly on window reducing size without being covered by fixed menus?

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-ui, window-resize

I'm using Semantic-ui. The page I'm designing has **two fixed menus on both sides, and a container** for the content on the middle.

If I use two fixed menus on both sides, **the container on the middle gets covered by them** on window resizing.
Like this:
[image]

I would like the container to resize considering that, on both sides, there are two elements that occupy their own space.

### How can I make a container resize properly on window reducing size?

This snippet has an example from semantic-ui's webpage. It has two fixed menus on both sides an the same problem with the container, it get's covered by them.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/components/menu.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/components/item.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.css" />
<script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.js"></script>
  </head>

<div>
  <div class="ui left fixed vertical menu">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <a class="item">Features</a>
    <a class="item">Testimonials</a>
    <a class="item">Sign-in</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ui right fixed vertical menu">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <a class="item">Features</a>
    <a class="item">Testimonials</a>
    <a class="item">Sign-in</a>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <div class="ui container">
    <h1> I can't seee thiiiiiissss</h1>
  </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Since both sidebars have fixed width (15rem each) you can use [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to set a calculated width for the content container. With this you'll cover all desktop displays (down to 768px wide), but looks like this Semantic-ui have own breakpoints to change container's width dynamically, so any display with resolution lower than 768px will break this again. But this is not so misfortune, cause you're not going to show both this sidebars on such small screens, are you? You know, there's no room for them.

```css
div.ui.container {
  width: calc(100% - 30rem);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/components/menu.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/components/item.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.css" />
<script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.js"></script>
  </head>

<div>
  <div class="ui left fixed vertical menu">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <a class="item">Features</a>
    <a class="item">Testimonials</a>
    <a class="item">Sign-in</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ui right fixed vertical menu">
    <div class="item">
      Item
    </div>
    <a class="item">Features</a>
    <a class="item">Testimonials</a>
    <a class="item">Sign-in</a>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <div class="ui container">
    <h1> I can't seee thiiiiiissss</h1>
  </div>
<div>
```